# remote signing using Xcode

Tags: xcode, keychain, code-signing

I was wondering if Xcode support remote signing. This means signing my app with certificate that reside in keychain file that is located in remote machine.

Currently I use the `run script` option and copy my application to remote location, sign it and copy it back. The connection to the remote machine should be made without password using ssl authentication (which I've done once prior to the compilation phase). the script look like this :

```
1. scp <my_target> <user>@<server>:
2. /tmp/ssh <user>@<server> 'security unlock-keychain -p <password> \
<home>/Library/Keychains/login.keychain; codesign -f -s " \
<my_signature>" /tmp/<my_target>'
3. scp <user>@<server>:/tmp/<my_target> .
```

My question is whether Xcode have such remote signing capabilities, that replace my script.

Comment: Crickets on Ask Different - let's see if SO has some answers for you.